# Estoy usando rmarkdown con un chunk que corre en la consola pero no cuando lo ejecuto con el knit?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Instrucción en un chunk de rmarkdown:

1. stats::xtabs(~vio2010$P5 + vio2010$P6r + vio2010$P4, data = vio2010)
2. El data.frame vio2010 esta en el directorio de trabajo pero al hacer knit se detiene el proceso y da el siguiente mensaje de error:
3. ! objeto 'vio2010' no encontrado
   Backtrace:
   stats::xtabs(~vio2010$P5 + vio2010$P6r + vio2010$P4, data = vio2010)

Comment: Pues para responderte tendrías que compartir el código, el error por otro lado es bien claro, en la instancia de ejecución del chunk el objeto no existe

Comment: Configuraste el espacio de trabajo en el documento también? Si no lo haces, el espacio de trabajo es equivalente a la carperta contenedora del archivo *.Rmd